# GeoNetwork harvesting of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, metadata, geonetwork, csw

When I harvest my GeoServer WFS using GeoNetwork to create iso19139 records, the URL of the first entry within MD_DigitalTransferOptions is always:

http://localhost:8000/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature

This isn't particularly useful as that URL doesn't reference the feature and therefore can't be used as a service for that resource. The remaining entries in MD_DigitalTransferOptions correspond to different WFS outputFormats and do specify the typename within the URL element e.g:

http://localhost:8000/geoserver/wfs?request=GetFeature&request=GetFeature&service=WFS&typename=sf:archsites&outputFormat=KML&version=1.0.0

Is there a way to prevent the harvester creating the first entry e.g. either within GeoNetwork or possibly GeoServer WFS settings?